# Eloquent associate without JOIN

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I make a query for multiple tables witout using join? Like in this example:

```
select c.id_categoria, c.titulo
from categorias c, aulas_categorias ac
where c.disciplina='N' and c.id_categoria=ac.id_categoria and ac.id_aula in (1,2,3,4)
```

This query will return two fields from table "categorias", but with a condition from another table. So far the closest that I got in eloquent was:

```
$categorias = AulaCategorias
            ::with('categoria')
            ->select('categorias.id_categoria', 'categorias.titulo')
            ->whereIn('aulas_categorias.id_aula', array(1,2,3,4))
            ->get();
```

And this query returns

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categorias.id_categoria' in 'field list'
in PDOConnection.php line 77
at PDO->prepare('select `categorias`.`id_categoria`, `categorias`.`titulo` from `aulas_categorias` where `aulas_categorias`.`id_aula` in (?, ?, ?, ?)', array()) in PDOConnection.php line 77
```

If I remove the select line

```
->select('categorias.id_categoria', 'categorias.titulo')
```

the query returns a collection, so the relations are ok.

In summarizing, I'm looking for a way to turn the query that eloquent creates from

```
select `categorias`.`id_categoria`, `categorias`.`titulo` 
from `aulas_categorias` 
where `aulas_categorias`.`id_aula` in (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

to

```
select `categorias`.`id_categoria`, `categorias`.`titulo` 
from `aulas_categorias`, `categorias`
where `aulas_categorias`.`id_aula` in (?, ?, ?, ?) 
and 'categorias'.'id_categorias'='aulas_categorias'.'id_categorias'
and 'categorias'.'disciplina'='N'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations between the two tables is not clear if you can show your eloquent models in the question, we'll be able to help you.

But in general you can do something like this:

```
    $categorias = AulaCategorias::with(['categoria' => function($query){
       $query->select('id_categoria', 'titulo' )
}])->whereIn('id_aula', array(1,2,3,4))->get();
```

If that doesn't help, please add the relations between the two tables from your models.